# SetId() and then findviewById in java programmatically issue

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Hi i am trying to setId programmatically, but the issue is how to find that id after setting it in java. i am working in `fragments (Viewpager)`and here is my code below.

```
property=new SearchableSpinner(getActivity());
city.setId(R.id.citybuy);
town.setId(R.id.townbuy);
property.setId(R.id.propertybuy);

 city = (SearchableSpinner) this.view.findViewById(R.id.citybuy);
  town = (SearchableSpinner) this.view.findViewById(R.id.townbuy);
 property = (SearchableSpinner) this.view.findViewById(R.id.propertybuy);
```

and it didn't find `id` and shows `NullPointerException`
and if i `set id` through `XML` then it shows this `error`:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View
>   State but received class
>   gr.escsoft.michaelprimez.searchablespinner.SearchableSpinner$SavedState
>   instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have
>   the same id in the same hierarchy..This view's id is id/city_wanted.
>   Make sure other views do not use the same id

Though `id's` are different in all `fragments XML`

Comment: from your code above I assume that you didn't added your views to your layout

Comment: please make sure that you didn't used the same id twice..

Comment: How to set Views?

Comment: addView() is used to set your views to the layout

Answer (score 1):

what I believe you are setting id to the view in xml and also now you are setting the same id again to the same view.

Comment: i didn't set id in xml i just only set in java atrun time but the issue is how to find that id again in java? will u send me some sample of code?

Comment: @WaleedAsim double check your code twice. This problem will arise when you use same id twice.

Comment: @SudheeshR i check my code whole day. and changed every id in those layouts but still issue

Comment: okay then try to set random numbers as id. for eg. city.setId(R.id.1212);
town.setId(R.id.0202); and check still this exists.